# How to store time from chrono inside a double?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have a class with private member:

```
std::chrono::duration<double> _time;
```

and inside a member function I have:

```
auto time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto deltaTime  = time - _time;
.
.
.
_time = time;
```

I want to use `deltaTime` for other things that require a double value, but I don't know how to turn it into one. All the chrono tutorials just seem to print the result and never change it into a double...

eg..

```
double dTime = convert(deltaTime); // converts time to nanoseconds
```

Comment: `deltaTime` is a `time_point`. What kind of value are you expecting from it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley a double... or is it not possible?

Comment: What would the `double` store? `time_point - duration = time_point`, no?

Comment: I don't mean what storage format, but what meaning are you looking for from this number? It's a point in time. How would you represent, for example, "January 4th, at 10:54.932345 pm, 2018" as a double?

Comment: The time in nanoseconds - sorry i was under the impression that was what the time variable was holding in the first place

Comment: Nanoseconds is a duration. You have a time point. You can't represent a point in time in nanoseconds.

Comment: is there any way to get some sort of delta time using chrono? or is that not its use

Comment: Sure. Subtract one time point from another. That will give you a duration (the amount of time between those two time points). Right now you're subtracting a duration from a time point though. That gives you another time point. Perhaps you want to change `_time` to be a time point?

Comment: You already have a delta time deltaTime compare that against nanoseconds{some value}

Comment: @Aram: No he doesn't. His variable may be named that. But it is incorrectly named, because it is storing a time point, not a duration (which is a change or 'delta' in time).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You're right I missed the _time variable definition, although he is almost there of getting a real delta if he changes the _time variable to a time_point

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but here's a common pattern. Let's say you want to execute a loop, and get the number of seconds each iteration takes, in order to pass that to some function which is expecting a double representing seconds.

```
using clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

// this is a time_point
auto lastIteration = clock_t::now();

while (true) {
    // this is a time_point
    auto thisIteration = clock_t::now();

    // time_point - time_point = duration
    auto elapsed = thisIteration - lastIteration;
    lastIteration = thisIteration;

    // don't need to pass ratio, because default is 1/1, which is seconds
    double seconds = std::chrono::duration<double>(elapsed).count();
    someFunction(seconds);
}
```

If you want nanoseconds, you could of course just multiply the seconds by 1 billion. Or you could use:

```
double nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(elapsed).count();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I actually think what I need is to just get the time in seconds from chrono, and store it as a double. I tried to use the cast on a time point but it doesnt work. :(

Comment: *"get the time in seconds from chrono"* -- Time in seconds of what?

Comment: time in seconds since arbitrary date or perhaps since program began

Comment: @TheoWalton: You should be able to easily adapt the code I provided to get that. Just store the time with a call to `now()` when the program begins. And whenever you want to check how much time has elapsed, just call `now()` again, and subtract the original time from it. Just don't overwrite the original time like I am in my loop.

Comment: @TheoWalton - For the process times you can use `GetProcessTimes()` on Windows or `times()` on linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto ns = 
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(time.time_since_epoch()).count();
std::cout << "nanoseconds since epoch " << ns << std::endl;
```

or

```
auto time1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
_sleep(1000);
auto time2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto ns = 
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(time2-time1).count();
std::cout << "nanoseconds " << ns << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do. You should avoid using .count() if possible. If you want to check how many nanoseconds have passed since a time point then something like this should suffice

```
auto old_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// ...
auto new_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
if (new_time - old_time > nanoseconds{value}) { 
    // do something
}
```

If you need to get the real value in a double or whatever because you're passing to a library that can't handle chrono then as the other answers pointed out you could do something in the lines of

```
double nanosecs = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(new_time - old_time).count()
```